# What is the bkp component in a presale JSON file?

Tags: password, presale, sha3

Is the "bkp" component of a presale json file a SHA3 hash of the wallet password?

Answer (score 3):

No. Your bkp is not the SHA3 of your password.

It's really quite simple. In the beginning, god said genwallet and...

1. [genwallet says](https://github.com/tagawa/website/blob/master/pyethtool/pyethtool.py#L129):

   - `genwallet(opts['seed'],pw,email)`
2. You say "here's my email and pw"
3. [seed says "give me super random number"](https://github.com/tagawa/website/blob/master/pyethtool/pyethtool.py#L55):

   - `seed = random_key().decode('hex') # uses pybitcointools' 3-source random generator`
4. [so now you need to get your `encseed`](https://github.com/tagawa/website/blob/master/pyethtool/pyethtool.py#L56):

   - `encseed = aes.encryptData(pbkdf2(pw),seed)`
5. [so we head over to mr. aes and say whats up](https://github.com/tagawa/website/blob/master/pyethtool/aes.py#L590-L611):

   - `def encryptData(key, data, mode=AESModeOfOperation.modeOfOperation["CBC"], iv=None):`
   - `........`
   - `........`
6. **and now you have your encseed.**
7. [then you get the `ethpriv](https://github.com/tagawa/website/blob/master/pyethtool/pyethtool.py#L57):

   - `ethpriv = sha3(seed)`
8. [and your `address`](https://github.com/tagawa/website/blob/master/pyethtool/pyethtool.py#L59):

   - `ethaddr = sha3(privtopub(ethpriv)[1:])[12:].encode('hex')`
9. [and finally your bkp](https://github.com/tagawa/website/blob/master/pyethtool/pyethtool.py#L61):

   - `bkp = sha3(seed + '\x02').encode('hex')`
10. **So your bkp is the sha3 of your seed plus essentially the number "2" (number "1" was used for your btcpriv to differentiate it from your ethpriv) encoded in hex**.
11. The bkp is a backup obviously. But its not a backup of your password. Its a backup of your seed.

    print "Your seed is:", getseed(b['withwallet'],w['bkp'],b['ethaddr'])

leads to...

```
def recover_bkp_pw(bkp,pw):
return getseed(bkp['withpw'],pw,bkp['ethaddr'])
....
"withpw": aes.encryptData(pbkdf2(pw),seed).encode('hex'),
```

or...

```
def recover_bkp_wallet(bkp,wallet):
return getseed(bkp['withwallet'],wallet['bkp'],bkp['ethaddr'])
...
"withwallet": aes.encryptData(pbkdf2(wallet['bkp']),seed).encode('hex'),
```

Get it now?

---

[same post / comment on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5ees2q/is_the_bkp_component_of_a_presale_json_file_a/)